# Problem in commandbutton with immediate="true"

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have `<apex:commandbutton>` in a repeat section. I want that when submit is peformed of a single section it does not encounter the validations of other sections, so I am using immediate = true. The problem I am facing is my data does not post on server.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!listVal}" var="record"/>
  <apex:repeat value="{!Fields}" var="f">
    <apex:inputField value="{!record[f]}" required="{!OR(f.required,f.dbrequired)}" />
  </apex:repeat>

 <apex:commandbutton value="submit" action="{!save}" immediate="true" />    
</apex:repeat>
```

I have checked, and i found that it is the behaviour of which does not allow to post data to server. How should I implement this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well Pankaj whenever you are setting `immediate="true"` for a command button the validations along with the setter for the fields doesnt fire and hence data is not posted to server/controller.

You can also try to enclose sections inside `<apex:ActionRegion>` this will allow you submit the corresponding section to the server.

Something like this probably

```
<apex:repeat value="{!listVal}" var="record"/>
    <apex:ActionRegion>
      <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
          <apex:repeat value="{!Fields}" var="f">
            <apex:inputField value="{!record[f]}" required="{!OR(f.required,f.dbrequired)}" />
          </apex:repeat>

            <apex:commandbutton value="submit" action="{!save}" rerender="panel" />
     </apex:outputPanel> 
   <apex:ActionRegion>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: @Pankaj updated the answer.

Comment: These days you can also use multiple <apex:form>s to achieve the same effect as the action regions.